# onUnload function is not working for mozilla

Tags: javascript

onUnload is not working for mozilla but the same function is working fine for IE.

Below is the code sample :

```
<body style="background-color: gainsboro;" onload="SetScrollPosition()" onUnload="LogMeOut()">
```

Please suggest me the resolution.

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, please include it in your question.

Comment: Please show function LogMeOut too - you cannot reliably do something with the current window in the onUnload

Comment: Also, you've asked 16 questions but have never accepted an answer. Please go back through your questions and if there was an answer that solved your problem, press the checkmark beside it to mark it as **accepted**. See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you install the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin, it has a javascript debugger which should allow you find the issue.